# Bind ListBoxFor (Multiple) back to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a MVC view that renders what basically equates to a KeyValuePair using the Razor syntax below, and then generating the following HTML.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItems, new SelectList(Model.SelectedItems, "Key", "Key"), new { Class = "selectList selectedList", size = "2" })
```

HTML:

```
<select class="selectList selectedList" id="SelectedItems" name="SelectedItems" size="2">
   <option value="842">Item 1</option>
   <option value="326">Item 2</option>
   <option value="327">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

I am posting the form manually using Jquery and generic function to POST our forms, as below:

```
function GenericSubmit(formSelector, sender, callback) {
    if (typeof (sender) != "undefined" && $(sender).hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    var $that = $(formSelector);
    var that = $that.get(0);
    if ($that.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: that.action,
            type: that.method,
            data: $(that).serialize(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback.call(that, data);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

However the issue I am experiencing, is that only data that is being sent is the actual values (I expect this is how JQ works..), but I need to bind to an IEnumerable.

From looking at the POST data that is sent to the form, I can only see the following values being sent - which I would expect why my Model has a null collection.

```
SelectedItems:842
SelectedItems:326
SelectedItems:327
```

My Model is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// An response for dealing with list type entities
/// </summary>
public class ListEntityResponse : EntityScreenResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains a Enumerable of items that can be selected
    /// </summary>
    public List<KeyValueViewModel> AvailableItems { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains a Enumerable of items that have been selected
    /// </summary>
    public List<KeyValueViewModel> SelectedItems { get; set; }

    public ListEntityResponse()
    {
        AvailableItems = new List<KeyValueViewModel>();

        SelectedItems = new List<KeyValueViewModel>();
    }


}
```

For added clarity - here is my KeyValueViewModel:

```
 public class KeyValueViewModel
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: Current Results]

I've searched high and low for this, but can't seem to find anything on the subject that works, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

//Just realized I had misread your question.

If you want yo bind to multiple values you need to use ListBoxFor

//

So why do you need the controller to receive all this info from the view if its something that you probably already have in your backend?

It makes sense for it to only care about the things you submitted in the form.

If what you need is to repopulate this data to render the view again (because there were validation errors, here's an elegant approach)

http://www.paulstovell.com/clean-aspnet-mvc-controllers

Comment: Yes I will have it in my backend, but I don't really want to hit the DB again, for this data.. But I do agree it should only care about things submitted in the form... but on the other hand, I do need it as a IEnum because it will be used for rendering the items so they can edit there selections.

Thanks for the link - I'll give it a read over, and see what Chuck Norris says!

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid, I've added an image to help illustrate my issue